# http://[app-name].herokuapp.com/socket.io/1/?t=1436904053183 404 Not Found

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, socket.io

I am having the following error on my web site.

> http://[app-name].herokuapp.com/socket.io/1/?t=1436904053183 404 Not Found

My app it is a chat build it with Socket.io. I did a research and figure out that the port it is listening in 45361 (this port is set by Heroku) and my client.js it is listening in a diferent one. How can I tell my client.js to listen from the same port like my server.js file?

My server.js file looks like this:

```js
app.configure(function() {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('ipaddr', process.env.IP || "127.0.0.1");
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
    app.use('/icons', express.static(__dirname + '/icons'));
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

    /* Store process-id (as priviledged user) */
    try {
        npid.create('/var/run/advanced-chat.pid', true);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        //process.exit(1);
    }

});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running on port:" + app.get('port'))
})
```

and in my file client.js I got something like this:

```
var socket = io.connect("//[app-name].herokuapp.com");
```

Also I tried:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://[app-name].herokuapp.com/");
```

Appreciate your time!

Comment: Have you tried connecting without passing the url as a parameter?
`var socket = io.connect();`
That is [working for me](https://github.com/gastonmancini/node-chat/blob/master/public/scripts/services/socketService.js#L8).

Comment: Yes, I did it but I got the same result in the Chrome console.

http://[app-name].herokuapp.com/socket.io/1/?t=1436905535251

Comment: Does your chat it is deployed on Heroku?

Comment: Yes it is [here](http://chat-node-tio.herokuapp.com/). Sorry for not being able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you can try to form correctly the url in the client side

```
    window.location.origin = window.location.origin || (window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':' + window.location.port);
    var socket = io.connect(window.location.origin);
```

Comment: I tried out this option too and I got the same error. Is there another way to specify the port? I found this article which is showing almost the same error like me. http://www.jchansen.org/2014/03/28/getting-a-node-js-socket-io-app-to-work-when-deployed-to-heroku/ 

In this post the Author set in Heroku the port 80 every time I deploy the app is deployed in a different port.

Comment: I read that some people used only the windows.location.hostname:
`var socket = io.connect(window.location.hostname);`

Comment: Not sure if this is something different but the message I got after testing your last suggestion changed to this:
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)